# Vue Multiselect: Access object within object for custom option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, multi-select, vue-component

I am using the [Vue Multiselect Custom Option Template](https://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/#sub-custom-option-template)
and I want to use the name property as a `customLabel`normally this would be easy as just using `name` but in this case the property I need is within another object.

Here is the object I am bringing in:

```
0:Object
  created_at:null
  id:1
  profile:Object
    id:1
    picture_url:"some-image.jpg"
    profile_id:"your-id"
    profile_name:"Your Name"
    profile_id:1
  subscription_active:1
  updated_at:null
```

Normally name would be in the root so it would easy to access but I need to access `profile_name` which is nested under `profile`

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
methods: {
  customLabel ({ profile['profile_name'] }) {
  return `${ profile['profile_name'] }`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
methods: {
  customLabel ({ profile }) {
  return `${ profile.profile_name }`
}
```

Comment: Bravo, that works, BTW has anyone ever told you that you look just like Pachenko from Death Race?